# Azure App Service : Can't Add custom domain

Tags: azure-web-app-service

After I registered DNS Zone, I tried to validate my domain to add custom domain, But still can't work.And got an error in the last line with the content "To verify domain ownership create TXT and A records with your DNS provider using the configuration below".

The DNS I have registered is ftq-test.biz

I also added 2 records as follows:

- A : host: @, TTL: 3600, Value : my IP
- TXT : host: asuid, TTL:3600, Value: Custom Domain Verification ID.

What step am I missing?
Please help me.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGOxb.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IstU5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the DNS Zone to work for your domain, you need to make sure your domain uses the Azure DNS as its Nameservers. Normally, this is configured at the domain registrar like GoDaddy or Namecheap.

To check if the domain is setup correctly, you can do an [NS Lookup](https://dnschecker.org/ns-lookup.php). The result should show Azure as the nameservers for your domain:

[image: Nameserver overview]

Checking the nameservers for your domain name, it looks like nameservers weren't set up yet.

[image: ftq-test.biz results]

**EDIT:**
Seems like you haven't even registered that domain yet. You will need to first register (buy) the domain, then configure it to use Azure DNS as its nameservers and only then you can connect it as a custom domain name to your Azure App Service.

[image: ftq-test.biz is still available]

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice.
I've done it already.
Hope good things come to you.

Answer (score 0):

This is my checklist that I use for setting up an azure hosted app service with one of my godaddy domains:

```
Example assuming appservice is called myAppService  and your desired sub-domain at front of url is mySubDomain  
1.  Go to azure portal.  Navigate to the appservice.
2.  click on 'Custom domains' blade
3.  grey + symbol is actually a button, 'Add custom domain'
4.  type in full url e.g. mySubdomain.mydomain.co.uk   Validate.
5.  Copy the Custom Domain Verification ID should be like A5A80F074A83A677E103B749F31237B08B630D5D1B0D79040E410FCDF802BAF8
6.   godaddy.com.   login.    top right, choose yourname then 'My Products'  
7.  mydomain.co.uk click DNS on the right
8.  Add.  TXT.
1.  Name = asuid.mySubdomain  (the subdomain)
2.  Value = A5A80F074A83A677E103B749F37507B08B630D5D1B0D72050E410FCDF801AAF8
3.  TTL = 1 hour
4.  Add record.
9.  Add.  CNAME.   
1.  Name = the subdomain you wish to use e.g. mySubdomain 
2.  Value = the azuresites url e.g. myAppService.azurewebsites.net
3.  TTL 1 hour
4.  Add record
10. Go back to to azure and Validate again it should work.
11. Add custom domain
12. It should appear within Custom Domains blade but with SSL state Not Secure
13. Click Add Binding under the SSL Binding column
14. The panel that appears on the right is buggy it often says you have no certificates but if you click custom domain to 'Choose domain' then back again, your certificate appears
15. Choose certificate (not the expired one)
16. TLS / SSL type is 'SNI SSL'
17. Add Binding
18. Should now show up as secure
19. Click the slider that says HTTPS only to true
20. You are done.
```